# Using nested case statements somewhat like a loop?

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle10g, nested, case

```
TASKS         DATE
NOD 1 OUT     2/5/10
NOD 1 IN      NULL 
NOD 2 OUT     2/10/10
NOD 2 IN      2/11/10
NOD 3 OUT     2/15/10
NOD 3 IN      NULL
```

What I need to do is find Find the greatest NOD, then if the NOD has an IN date, place 'NO NOD' in the row, but if the greatest NOD has been sent OUT but not received back IN, calculate the number of days since it was sent out.  I am attempting to nest the case statements, but what is happening is that it is seeing the NOD 2 OUT then IN and placing the 'No NOD' text.  I can't figure out how to get it to find the greatest NOD.  Here is what I have so far (I am newer to SQL, so I apologize if anything is way off and I know my formatting is bad, but I can see what goes with what better this way.):

```
CASE 
             WHEN COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_NOD_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE) = '0' THEN 'No NOD Out'
             WHEN  MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_2.COMPLETED_DATE) IS NOT NULL AND MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_5.COMPLETED_DATE) IS NOT NULL 
             THEN    (CASE 
                      WHEN MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_3.COMPLETED_DATE) IS NOT NULL AND MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_6.COMPLETED_DATE) IS NOT NULL 
                      THEN    (CASE
                               WHEN MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_4.COMPLETED_DATE) IS NOT NULL AND MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_7.COMPLETED_DATE) IS NOT NULL 
                               THEN 'No NOD Out_3'
                               ELSE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE - (MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE)))) 
                               END)
                      ELSE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE - (MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE))))
                      END) 
             ELSE TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE - (MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE))))
             END   AS "Days Since Last NOD",
```

I have aliased the tables so that I touch the table once per each task, as such:

```
DATE_NOD_TBL contains all OUT tasks
DATE_NOD_TBL_2 is NOD 1 OUT
DATE_NOD_TBL_3 is NOD 2 OUT
DATE_NOD_TBL_4 is NOD 3 OUT
DATE_NOD_TBL_5 is NOD 1 IN
DATE_NOD_TBL_6 is NOD 2 IN
DATE_NOD_TBL_7 is NOD 3 IN
```

I am using 10g Oracle SQL.

Entire Query:

```
SELECT DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TYPE_LABEL       AS "Project Type",
  MAX(DATE_ISSUED_TBL_3.ASSIGNED_STAFF_ID)                  AS "Project Manager",
  AGENCY_INTEREST_ALT.ALTERNATE_AI_ID                          AS "Farm ID #",
  MTB_PARISH_COUNTY.PARISH_OR_COUNTY_DESC             AS "County",
  MAX(DISTINCT AGENCY_INTEREST.MASTER_AI_NAME)        AS "Operation Name",
  MAX(DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE)                   AS "Date Received",
  MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE)                            AS "NOD Date",
  COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_NOD_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE)         AS "# of NOD's",

--//days since last NOD
 CASE
    WHEN GREATEST(MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_2.COMPLETED_DATE),
                  MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_3.COMPLETED_DATE), 
                  MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_4.COMPLETED_DATE)) <
         GREATEST(MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_5.COMPLETED_DATE), 
                  MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_6.COMPLETED_DATE), 
                  MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_7.COMPLETED_DATE)) 
         THEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE - (MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE))))
    ELSE 'No NOD Out'
END AS "Days Since Last NOD",


  --//net time
  CASE WHEN 
    COUNT(DISTINCT DATE_NOD_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE) = '0' 
      THEN TRUNC(MAX(SYSDATE - DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE))
    ELSE
  TRUNC(MAX((SYSDATE - DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE) - 
  --//issued NOD #1/NOD #1 Information Received
  NVL(((CASE WHEN DATE_NOD_TBL_5.STATUS_CODE IS NULL THEN SYSDATE ELSE DATE_NOD_TBL_5.COMPLETED_DATE END) - DATE_NOD_TBL_2.COMPLETED_DATE),'0') -
  --//issued NOD #2/NOD #2 Information Received
  NVL(((CASE WHEN DATE_NOD_TBL_6.STATUS_CODE IS NULL THEN SYSDATE ELSE DATE_NOD_TBL_6.COMPLETED_DATE END) - DATE_NOD_TBL_3.COMPLETED_DATE),'0') -  
  --//issued NOD #3/NOD #3 Information Received
  NVL(((CASE WHEN DATE_NOD_TBL_7.STATUS_CODE IS NULL THEN SYSDATE ELSE DATE_NOD_TBL_7.COMPLETED_DATE END) - DATE_NOD_TBL_4.COMPLETED_DATE),'0')   
  )) END
  AS "Net Time",


  TRUNC(MAX(SysDate - DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE))  AS "Gross Time",
  MAX(DATE_SITEASSESSMENT_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE)             AS "Site Visit"
FROM DSK_CENTRAL_FILE
INNER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_ISSUED_TBL
ON DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID       = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_ISSUED_TBL.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '171'
AND DATE_ISSUED_TBL.STATUS_CODE      IS NULL
INNER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_ISSUED_TBL_2
ON DATE_ISSUED_TBL_2.MASTER_AI_ID       = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_ISSUED_TBL_2.INT_DOC_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_ISSUED_TBL_2.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '163'
AND DATE_ISSUED_TBL_2.STATUS_CODE      IS NULL
INNER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_ISSUED_TBL_3
ON DATE_ISSUED_TBL_3.MASTER_AI_ID       = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_ISSUED_TBL_3.INT_DOC_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_ISSUED_TBL_3.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '262'
INNER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_RECEIVED_TBL
ON DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID       = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID        = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID      = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '571'
AND DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.STATUS_CODE       = '001'
AND DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE   IS NOT NULL
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_NOD_TBL
ON DATE_NOD_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL.INT_DOC_ID         = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL.INT_DOC_ID         = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID       = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL.REFERENCE_TASK_ID IN ( '393','394','395')
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_NOD_TBL_8
ON DATE_NOD_TBL_8.MASTER_AI_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_8.INT_DOC_ID         = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_8.INT_DOC_ID         = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_8.MASTER_AI_ID       = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_8.REFERENCE_TASK_ID  IN('602','603','608')
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_NOD_TBL_2
ON DATE_NOD_TBL_2.MASTER_AI_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_2.INT_DOC_ID         = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_2.INT_DOC_ID         = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_2.MASTER_AI_ID       = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_2.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '393'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_NOD_TBL_3
ON DATE_NOD_TBL_3.MASTER_AI_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_3.INT_DOC_ID         = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_3.INT_DOC_ID         = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_3.MASTER_AI_ID       = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_3.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '394'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_NOD_TBL_4
ON DATE_NOD_TBL_4.MASTER_AI_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_4.INT_DOC_ID         = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_4.INT_DOC_ID         = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_4.MASTER_AI_ID       = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_4.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '395'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_NOD_TBL_5
ON DATE_NOD_TBL_5.MASTER_AI_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_5.INT_DOC_ID         = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_5.INT_DOC_ID         = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_5.MASTER_AI_ID       = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_5.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '603'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_NOD_TBL_6
ON DATE_NOD_TBL_6.MASTER_AI_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_6.INT_DOC_ID         = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_6.INT_DOC_ID         = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_6.MASTER_AI_ID       = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_6.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '602'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_NOD_TBL_7
ON DATE_NOD_TBL_7.MASTER_AI_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_7.INT_DOC_ID         = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_7.INT_DOC_ID         = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_7.MASTER_AI_ID       = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_NOD_TBL_7.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '608'
LEFT OUTER JOIN ACTIVITY_TASK_LIST DATE_SITEASSESSMENT_TBL
ON DATE_SITEASSESSMENT_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID       = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_SITEASSESSMENT_TBL.INT_DOC_ID        = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_SITEASSESSMENT_TBL.INT_DOC_ID        = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.INT_DOC_ID
AND DATE_SITEASSESSMENT_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID      = DATE_ISSUED_TBL.MASTER_AI_ID
AND DATE_SITEASSESSMENT_TBL.REFERENCE_TASK_ID = '201'
INNER JOIN DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE
ON DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_CATEGORY_CODE  = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.ACTIVITY_CATEGORY_CODE
AND DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_CLASS_CODE    = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.ACTIVITY_CLASS_CODE
AND DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE     = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.ACTIVITY_TYPE_CODE
AND DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.PROGRAM_CODE           = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.PROGRAM_CODE
AND DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.PROGRAM_CODE           = 'CF'
AND DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_CATEGORY_CODE = 'ATH'
LEFT OUTER JOIN AGENCY_INTEREST_ALT
ON AGENCY_INTEREST_ALT.MASTER_AI_ID   = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND AGENCY_INTEREST_ALT.END_DATE     IS NULL
AND AGENCY_INTEREST_ALT.USER_GROUP_ID = 'CFO'
INNER JOIN AGENCY_INTEREST
ON AGENCY_INTEREST.MASTER_AI_ID = AGENCY_INTEREST_ALT.MASTER_AI_ID
AND AGENCY_INTEREST.INT_DOC_ID  = AGENCY_INTEREST_ALT.INT_DOC_ID
INNER JOIN SUBJ_ITEM_LOC_GOV_WITHIN
ON SUBJ_ITEM_LOC_GOV_WITHIN.MASTER_AI_ID = DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.MASTER_AI_ID
AND SUBJ_ITEM_LOC_GOV_WITHIN.INT_DOC_ID  = AGENCY_INTEREST_ALT.INT_DOC_ID
INNER JOIN MTB_PARISH_COUNTY
ON MTB_PARISH_COUNTY.PARISH_OR_COUNTY_CODE = SUBJ_ITEM_LOC_GOV_WITHIN.PARISH_OR_COUNTY_CODE
WHERE DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.PROGRAM_CODE          = 'CF'
AND DSK_CENTRAL_FILE.INT_DOC_ID             != 0
AND AGENCY_INTEREST_ALT.INT_DOC_ID           = 0
GROUP BY DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TYPE_LABEL,
  AGENCY_INTEREST_ALT.ALTERNATE_AI_ID,
  MTB_PARISH_COUNTY.PARISH_OR_COUNTY_DESC
ORDER BY DSKMTB_ACTIVITY_TYPE.ACTIVITY_TYPE_LABEL,
MAX(DATE_RECEIVED_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE)
```

Comment: Can you include the rest of the query (at least, the joins and the group by)?

Comment: I added the query.  It's pretty beastly.

Comment: I can see what you mean!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To compare the largest IN date with the largest OUT date, try:

```
CASE
    WHEN GREATEST(MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_2.COMPLETED_DATE),
                  MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_3.COMPLETED_DATE), 
                  MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_4.COMPLETED_DATE)) <
         GREATEST(MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_5.COMPLETED_DATE), 
                  MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_6.COMPLETED_DATE), 
                  MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_7.COMPLETED_DATE)) 
         THEN TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE - (MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE))))
    ELSE 'No NOD Out'
END
```

To compare pairs of dates in turn, try:

```
DECODE(case
           when MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_4.COMPLETED_DATE) is not null
               then case when MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_7.COMPLETED_DATE) is null then 'T' end
           else
               case
                   when MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_3.COMPLETED_DATE) is not null
                       then case when MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_6.COMPLETED_DATE) is null then 'T' end
                   else
                       case
                           when MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_2.COMPLETED_DATE) is not null
                               then case when MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL_5.COMPLETED_DATE) is null then 'T' end
                       end
               end
       end, 'T',TO_CHAR(TRUNC(SYSDATE - (MAX(DATE_NOD_TBL.COMPLETED_DATE)))), 'No NOD Out')
```

Comment: I'm pretty sure that is having the same error that I was.  Because NOD #2 is both OUT and IN, it is stopping there, not calculating the days for the NOD 3 that is outstanding.

Comment: Actually, the fault here is because NOD 2 IN is after NOD 3 OUT - I was assuming that you wouldn't have a new OUT before the previous IN.

Comment: The data is a little bit of a mess and I am trying to work around it.  Sorry, maybe I should have said that.

Comment: @user1983682: I have updated the answer with an alternative solution - can you try the amended version?